# using a fadeOut double the number of div

Tags: jquery, click, fadeout

I have a problem with a `fadeOut()`.  My `<div>`'s are multiplied by two if I use the `fadeOut()`, but if I just make the `<div>`'s appear directly (with no fade on the `<div>`'s), there's no problem. Do you know what I could do for that?

Here's the line that does not work (after a click, it gives me two `<div>`'s instead of one, then if I click again four `<div>`'s appear, etc.)

```
div.fadeOut().empty().append(content).fadeIn('fast', function(){
```

and the one that works (but I'd like to have the `fadeOut` though):

```
div.empty().append...
```

and the entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loader = $('#loading');
    var div = $("#provisoire");

    div.append($(".content:first").html()).css({'display':'block'});

    $(".plus").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
        changeContent(name);
        return false;
    });

    function changeContent(name){
        var content = (name)?$("#"+name).html():$(".content:first").html();
        loader.fadeIn();
        $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 600, function(){
            div.empty().append(content).fadeIn('fast', function(){ //*** here
                loader.fadeOut();
                if(name){
                    div.find('.childB').append('<a href="#" style="background:green;" class="retour">Retour</div>');
                    div.find('.retour').click(function(){
                        changeContent();
                        return false;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(".plus").click(function(){
                        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
                        changeContent(name);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do....

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin : i have an empty div, that will receive the content of the website : it will receive the content of the first div if we click on the first div link, same thing with the other divs at the bottom (there are only 3 divs). Everything is made with ajax, so that the page is only loaded once. Maybe check the link if it can help. Thanks if you can help ! ;)

Comment: In your OP, you said, _"click on the `<div>` at the bottom"_.  Where?  There are three `<div>`'s across the top and none below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tentonaxe's solution, try using either html or body on the following line:

```
 $('html').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 600, function(){
```

I think having both html and body defined might call the callback function twice.

Comment: man thanks a lot! it was actually that, i remember though that i had to use both for a reason in another project, maybe for compatibility with all the browsers? i don't remember, if you something about that, but thanks a lot, i tried on Safari, Chrome and Firefox and it works! Maybe IE? i'll try if i can, thanks for posting!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, but if it works in IE probably not keeping and your solution will be sound. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

try using the callback function of the fadeOut to empty and append content that way it isn't emptied and appended before it is done fading out:

```
div.fadeOut('fast',function(){
  div.empty().append(content).fadeIn('fast',function(){
    ...
  });
});
```

Edit: Also, your primary problem, bind to the .plus class using `.live('click')` and only do it once, preferably outside of the `$(document).ready()`, however that would take some rearranging.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loader = $('#loading');
    var div = $("#provisoire");

    div.append($(".content:first").html()).css({'display':'block'});

    $(".plus").live('click',function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
        changeContent(name);
        return false;
    });
    $('.retour').live('click',function(){
      changeContent();
      return false;
    });

    function changeContent(name){
        var content = (name)?$("#"+name).html():$(".content:first").html();
        loader.fadeIn();
        $('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 600, function(){
            div.empty().append(content).fadeIn('fast', function(){ //*** here
                loader.fadeOut();
                if(name){
                    div.find('.childB').append('<a href="#" style="background:green;" class="retour">Retour</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, i uploaded the new version (here : www.pondb.com), but i still have a problem : if i click on "retour" to come back to the front page, it works, but if you click on the first div named "bio", it will let the new div appear twice, and "retour" will appear twice also. Do you understand why?

Comment: yes, i didn't remove the retour click binding. you should bind it with .live too, updating my response.

Comment: What was actually happening is the click events were being bound multiple times, therefore their handlers were being ran multiple times, thus creating multiple divs. By binding them one time using `.live()`, you avoid that situation.

Comment: @Paul, by updating your example page, people just coming here to help you are no longer seeing the same thing you originally described.  This thread will be confusing to future readers looking for help.

Comment: @Sparky672 : yeah, but you know i will have to change the page anyway after i found out the problem, and i did ;) i had to use $('html') instead of "html,body". thanks anyway

Comment: @Tentonaxe : thanks man, for your great help, i had to put only one selector : html, instead of html,body . Thanks anyway, i really appreciate ;) Cheers